# Relation of Stocks, Bond and Yield to each other in Market

Tags: stock-markets, government-bonds

I have been told by Financial advisors that I have to diversify in stocks and bonds to reduce risk of losing money in stocks.

I have attached the chart of DOW and 10 Year Treasury note below.

My questions are:

1. When the DOW fall, does not the Bond value go higher?
2. Is 10 Year Treasury Yield and the Bond Value the same?
3. If 10 Year Treasury Note the same as Bond, from the two charts both the Stock Market and Bond are going low. Rather it should be opposite like stocks go down but the Treasury Yield go higher?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sometimes the market and the long bonds correlate, sometimes not. Note the period of 2016 to 2020.  In the first two years, yield was  rising while the market rose and in the latter two years, yield dropped while the market rose.

Here's 20 years of the DJIA:

[image]

Here's 20 years of the 10 year bond:

[image]

Comment: But since bond *prices* rise when *yields* fall, that would **support** the notion that "bonds ... reduce risk of losing money in stocks".

Answer (score 1):

> When the DOW fall, does not the Bond value go higher?

No.  Bond values are -- by the nature of mathematics and our desire to get a fair rate of return -- **inversely** correlated to **interest rates**:

- when interest rates *fall*, the value of a bond *rises*;
- when interest rates *rise*, the value of a bond *falls*.